# Adding RAM to SQL server ruins performance

Tags: sql-server

Current setup:

We have a very large table that has a bigint pk and a nvarchar(1025) field.  The only index is the PK.
We have another table that is a bigint_fk to the first table with a checksum of the string field.

```
create table BigStringTable (
  id bigint identity(1,1) not null,
  dataString nvarchar(1025) not null,
  primary key clustered (id));
);

create table BigStringTableHashes(
 id bigint  not null,
  dataStringHash int not null,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_dataStringHash] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
      (
      [claid] dataStringHash
       )
    );
```

So you might query for something like:

```
SELECT datastring FROM BigStringTable AS bst
JOIN BigStringTableHashes AS hashes ON bst.id = hashes.id
WHERE hashes.dataStringHash = checksum(<Whatever String>) AND bst.dataString = '<Whatever String>'
```

The table is **very** large.

We have a very expensive server with 1.9 TB of RAM on amazon running all this.
Version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13) (KB4466404) - 14.0.3048.4 (X64)   Nov 30 2018 12:57:58   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
```

However, if we add more than about 900 GB of RAM the performance suddenly drops to a halt. And the query above starts reading massive amounts of data.  I know when changing the max memory it will clear out the cache, but it never recovers until we lower the max ram and reboot.

There is nothing else on this server.

As far as I can tell the query plans are the same, but it is hard to confirm because we can't drop it into this non-performing state too often, creating customer outages.

What I don't understand is how adding RAM ruins the performance.

Comment: What version of SQL server you use? What bitness?

Comment: Sorry, should have included that, Adding to question.

Comment: How is performance when you reboot the server (which obviously clears any memory cache)?

Comment: At first while it is warming up it is bad, but then stabilizes, if it has less than around 900GB of ram.

Comment: You said the server has 1.9 TB of RAM... what else is running on it? Do you limit SQL Server maximum usable memory? What do you mean by "adding more than 900 GB"? Please provide more details.

Comment: Also, this might be better answered on https://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Massimo It has 1.9 TB, nothing else is running on it, when I say "add memory" I mean increasing the max memory setting in SQL server.

Comment: Why is there a low max memory setting in the first place? Why didn't you leave it on default settings to use all available memory?

Comment: You might be running into some kind of NUMA issue.

Comment: +1 on NUMA issue. Investigate how windows/sql server handles NUMA.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try not to run a function on things and maybe consider partitioning by a useful key if you haven't already.

What does an explain say?

Hope that helps or sparks ideas.
BTW: Holy cow. that has got to be expensive with AWS. That is an insane amount of RAM.

Comment: The most expensive part is the SQL license, by a long shot.

Comment: But to answer your question, the query plan is as expected, index seek on the hash table, then an index seek on the string table.